# Search gives only one element from set

Tags: php, search

There is a small problem. I have this 3 functions, and this functions make search in DB. But, that search give only one element from category (when we have 2 or more).

For example, if we have 1,2,3 searche give us only
1.
If we delete 1, it will be 2 and etc.

Any suggestions?

This is 3 functions

```
function displayList($clause) {
    $clause = ' m.active=1 && g.active=1 && '.$clause;
    $pageSize = 12;
    $pageNo = isset($_GET['page'])? (int)$_GET['page']:0;
    $qr = "SELECT count(DISTINCT m.id) FROM #tyregoods g, #tyremodels m WHERE m.id = g.owner_id && $clause";
    $q = $this->execSQL($qr);
    list($count) = $q->get();
    $pageCount = ceil($count / $pageSize);
    if (!$pageCount) $pageCount = 1;
    if ($pageCount<=$pageNo) return false;
    $offset = $pageNo * $pageSize;

    list($sortV, $sort) = $this->getSort();

    /*$q = $this->execSQL("SELECT m.id as modelid, m.icon, m.name, m.season, g.id, width, profile, diameter, studed, indx, side, remains, price
    FROM #tyregoods g, #tyremodels m WHERE m.id = g.owner_id && $clause
    ORDER BY $sortV LIMIT $pageSize OFFSET $offset ");*/
    $q = "SELECT m.id as modelid, m.icon, m.name, m.season, g.id, width, profile, diameter, studed, indx, side, remains, price
    FROM #tyregoods g, #tyremodels m WHERE m.id = g.owner_id && $clause GROUP BY m.id
    ORDER BY $sortV LIMIT $pageSize OFFSET $offset";
    $q = $this->execSQL($q);
    $xml = '';
    while ($data = $q->getAssoc()) {
        $xml.=prop2xml($data);
    }
    return "<goodslist page='$pageNo' pagesize='$pageSize' pages='$pageCount' sort='$sort'>$xml</goodslist>";
}


function displayBySize() {
    $params = $this->kernel->getModul('tyreparams');
    $clause = $this->getSQLClause($params);

    if ($clause['where'] == '') return '<noparams/>';
    $xml = $this->displayList($clause).$params->display();
    return "<search>$xml</search>";
}

function getSQLClause($params, $except = array()) {
    $cl = array();

    foreach($params->params as $id=>$param) 
        if ($param['value']!='' && !in_array($id, $except)){
            $vl = trim($param['value']);
            if ('vendor' == $id) {
                $cl[] = "m.owner_id IN (SELECT ts.id FROM td_tyres ts WHERE ts.active=1 AND ts.id='$vl')";
            }
            else {
                $pos = strpos($vl, '-');
                if ($pos === 0) $pos = strpos($vl, '-', 1);
                if ($pos) {
                    $lo = substr($vl, 0, $pos);
                    $hi = substr($vl, $pos + 1);
                    $t = "$id >= '$lo' && $id <= '$hi'";
                }
                else
                    $t = "$id = '$vl'";

                if ($id == 'PCD') {
                    $t2 = str_replace('PCD', 'PCD2', $t);
                    $cl[] = "(($t) || ($t2))";
                } else
                    $cl[] = $t;
            }               
        }

    return implode('&&', $cl);
}
UPD

SQL query -
SELECT m.id as modelid, m.icon, m.name, m.season, g.id, width, profile, diameter,
studed, indx, side, remains, price FROM td_tyregoods g, td_tyremodels m WHERE m.id = 
g.owner_id && m.active=1 && g.active=1 && width = '245'&&profile = '50'&&m.owner_id IN 
(SELECT ts.id FROM td_tyres ts WHERE ts.active=1 AND ts.id='13') GROUP BY m.id ORDER BY 
name LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

This query, give in mysql console exactly that we have at the site. Problem in query...

Comment: Without looking at your code I'm pretty sure you are doing something in some loop which you shouldn't do.

Comment: `echo $q;` - then copy the code in phpmyadmin or mysql console and check what it does

Comment: PeeHaa - yes, maybe. I think it in getSQLClause function. But i can't make it in proper way..(( Maybe it have some connetion with strpos, because it function choose only fisrt that meet.